# Sendig explicit CURSOR as procedure parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have the folowing code. There's outer procedure having inner_procedure for processing cursors (concatenating data from cursor to m (message) variable). I can open cursor and send reference to inner procedure for processing like:

```
PROCEDURE outer_proc AS

  m VARCHAR2(2000):='';

  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;

  PROCEDURE inner_proc(cur IN SYS_REFCURSOR,m OUT VARCHAR2) IS
    firstname VARCHAR2(20);
    lastname VARCHAR2(20);
  BEGIN
    LOOP
      FETCH cur INTO firstname,lastname;
      EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
      m:=m||firstname||' '||lastname;
    END LOOP;
  END;

BEGIN

  OPEN cur FOR SELECT * FROM employees WHERE sallary<1000;
    inner_proc(cur,m);
  CLOSE cur;

  OPEN cur FOR SELECT * FROM employees WHERE sallary>=1000;
    inner_proc(cur,m);
  CLOSE cur;

END;
```

But I'd like to send explicit cursor name to inner procedure and leave inner procedure to open cursor and process it like:

```
PROCEDURE outer_proc AS

  TYPE cur_type IS REF CURSOR;

  m VARCHAR2(2000):='';

  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM employees WHERE sallary<1000;
  CURSOR c2 IS SELECT * FROM employees WHERE sallary>=1000;

  PROCEDURE inner_proc(cur IN cur_type,m OUT VARCHAR2) IS
    col1 VARCHAR2(20);
    col2 VARCHAR2(20);
  BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
      LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO col1,col2;
        EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
        m:=m||col1||' '||col2;
      END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
  END;

BEGIN

  inner_proc(c1,m);
  inner_proc(c2,m);

END;
```

In my example above cursors accidentally do have the same `%ROWTYPE` but inner_procedure cannot know that in advance. My inner procedure should receive as parameter an arbitrary cursor, open it and finally concatenate first and second cursor's columns to message.

In my first code using SYS_REFCURSOR in parameter I might send reference to different cursors as well, so... why I have to send reference of already opened cursor, I'd like that process of opening and closing cursor be the part of inner procedure. I'd like to send name of cursor and leave opening and closing (as traversing through, of course) to inner procedure.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You haven't shown the errors you get, but [formal parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/formal-parameter-declaration.html) have to be data types; a (non-REF) cursor is [not a data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html). Why are you trying to do this? You might be able to achieve a similar effect with `dbms_sql` but it's unclear whether it would be worth the effort and complication involved.

Comment: This would be kind a polymorhism in PL/SQL manner :-)

Comment: So really you want to pass an arbitrary cursor? Your example has the same projection for both, but if that's not the same the `%rowtype` wouldn't work either. I think you need to look at `dbms_sql` if you really want to go down that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation on explicit cursors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-89E0242F-42AC-4B21-9DF1-ACD6F4FC03B9) (emphasis added):

> You cannot assign a value to an explicit cursor, use it in an expression, **or use it as a formal subprogram parameter** or host variable. You can do those things with a cursor variable (see "[Cursor Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/static-sql.html#GUID-4A6E054A-4002-418D-A1CA-DE849CD7E6D5)").

So you cannot send an explicit cursor, `c1` or `c2` in your example - you can't have a procedure that takes an explicit cursor argument.

You are allowed to supply a *ref* cursor as a [formal parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-subprograms.html#GUID-9ACD7C7D-861B-4410-AC6F-8536C191E2EF), as you already doing. That could be an open cursor, as you have; or a cursor variable that you then open. But you don't really seem to want the cursor outside the procedure call, so neither seems quite what you want.

If you had a small-ish defined list of cursors you could literally pass the *name* of the cursor as a string, and then use a case statement in the procedure to open the relevant pre-defined cursor:

```
PROCEDURE outer_proc AS

  m VARCHAR2(2000):='';

  CURSOR c1 IS SELECT first_name,last_name FROM employees WHERE salary<1000;
  CURSOR c2 IS SELECT first_name,last_name FROM employees WHERE salary>=1000;

  PROCEDURE inner_proc(cur_name IN varchar2,m OUT VARCHAR2) IS
    col1 VARCHAR2(20);
    col2 VARCHAR2(20);
  BEGIN
    CASE cur_name
      WHEN 'c1' THEN
        OPEN c1;
        LOOP
          FETCH c1 INTO col1,col2; -- this will only work in the cursor only selects two columns!
          EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
          m:=m||col1||' '||col2;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c1;
      WHEN 'c2' THEN
        OPEN c2;
        LOOP
          FETCH c2 INTO col1,col2; -- this will only work in the cursor only selects two columns!
          EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;
          m:=m||col1||' '||col2;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c2;
    END CASE;
  END;

BEGIN

  inner_proc('c1',m);
  inner_proc('c2',m);

END;     
/
```

... but that's not scaleable and arguably already worse than what you have now.

Or pass the cursor *query*, rather than the cursor, into the procedure, and then open and process it with dynamic SQL. As that is what @Wernfried has demonstrated, I won't go into further detail. The possible downside of that though is that if you already have an explicit cursor that you are trying to reuse then you're now duplicating that query instead. Oh, and as it's dynamic, the query itself won't be parsed until run time, so an error might not be caught as early as you'd like.

TL;DR - see [@Wernfried's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58170989/266304) *8-)

Comment: I like your explanation and appreciate your effort in making the response, specially direct answer that I cannot send explicit cursor as I wanted. This solution with sending distingwisher 'c1','c2'... is not the solution I want (but you already knew that). In this example each cursor requires its own open/close code. I wanted one generic open/close functionality which will accept different cursors. However, I got the answer.

Comment: @sbrbot - it's always your decision of course, but if you're going to use the dbms_sql approach then I might have expected that answer to be accepted over this one. At least if you're going to use that code for your solution. <shrug> Glad the explantion helped you too though,

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason for an inner procedure, you can achieve it with a stand-alone procedure. When you pass a cursor to a procedure/function then it must be open, i.e. you cannot open the cursor inside the inner procedure.

It could be like this (not tested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_cursor(cur IN SYS_REFCURSOR) AS VARCHAR2 IS
    res VARCHAR2(10000);

    curid INTEGER;
    col_cnt INTEGER;
    rec_tab DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    v_rows_processed INTEGER;

    col_1 VARCHAR2(4000);
    col_2 VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN
    curid := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(cur);
    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(curid, col_cnt, rec_tab);  

    -- The generic approach
    /*
    FOR c in 1..col_cnt LOOP
        rec := rec_tab(c);
        IF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, c, num_var); 
        ELSIF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, c, string_var, rec.col_max_len); 
        ELSIF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, c, date_var); 
            -- .. some more data types if needed
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    */

    -- however you like to get only the first two columns which are strings.
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, 1, col_1, rec_tab(1).col_max_len);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, 2, col_2, rec_tab(2).col_max_len);

    v_rows_processed := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(curid);

    WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(curid) > 0 LOOP
        -- The generic approach
        /*
        FOR c IN 1..col_cnt LOOP
            rec := rec_tab(c);
            IF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, c, num_var); 
            ELSIF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, c, string_var); 
            ELSIF rec.col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, c, date_var); 
                -- .. some more data types if needed
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        */

        -- however you like to get only the first two columns which are strings.
      res := res || DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, 1, col_1)||' '||DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, 2, col_2);
    END LOOP; 

    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(curid);
    RETURN res;

END;
```

I prefer a FUNCTION rather than PROCEDURE if the procedure has just one single return value.

You would call the function like this:

```
DECLARE
    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    ret VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary < 1000;
    ret := process_cursor(cur);

    OPEN cur FOR SELECT * FROM customers WHERE turnover > 1000;
    ret := process_cursor(cur);

END;
```

If you insist to open the cursor inside the function then you have to pass the query as string. Could be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_cursor_str(sqlStr IN VARCHAR2) AS VARCHAR2 IS

    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    res VARCHAR2(10000);
    ...

BEGIN
    OPEN cur FOR sqlStr;
    curid := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(cur);
    ...


DECLARE
    ret VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
    ret := process_cursor_str('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary < 1000');       
    ret := process_cursor_str('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE turnover > 1000');    
END;
```

Comment: Thank you @Wernfried for your answer with using DBMS_SQL for dynamic processing of SQL, it is valuable too. But you know, I'm able to pick just one answer as a solution.